# Django - Assign Foreign Key upon Form submission

Tags: python, html, django

Hi I just started learning Django this week and am creating a to do list application, where a user can create multiple to-do lists, each list able to hold multiple items.

Models.py

```
class Todolist(models.Model):
    listname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Todo(models.Model):
    todoname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    whichlist = models.ForeignKey(Todolist, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Views.py

```
def dolist(request, list_id):
    tdlist = Todolist.objects.get(id=list_id)
    current_user = request.user
    user_todo = Todo.objects.filter(user=current_user, whichlist=tdlist)
    return render(request, 'todolist/tdlists.html', {'tdlist': tdlist, 'todos': user_todo,'list_id':list_id})

def addtodo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.user
        list_id = request.POST.get('list_id')
        Todo.objects.create(todoname = request.POST['todoname'], user=user, whichlist=list_id)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

.HTML Template form

```
<form action="/index/todolist/addtodo" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="list_id" value={{list_id}}>
    <input type="text" name="todoname"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add to-do item"/>
</form>
```

Right now, if I take out whichlist parameter in Todo.objects.create(), the to do item is able to be created upon form submission but the foreign key is not assigned so it won't show up on that todo list page. I can go to the Django admin site and manually assign whichlist for the Todo item, and it will then show up on that list page.

How can I make it so that the todo item's foreignkey is automatically assigned? i.e. mario todo item assigned to mario to do list

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: In your HTML form, you set `value={{list_id}}` but `list_id` isn’t defined in your context. Use the variables of your context.

Comment: I tried adding the context in for dolist.views but it did not work. Maybe I need to add context for the addtodo.views? I'm currently using HttpResponseRedirect to refresh the page (forgot to add that code in OP). Not sure if that supports context?

Comment: When you assign `whichlist` you need to give it a `Todolist` object not an id. Or you need to assign the id to `whichlist_id`.

Comment: Yep you're right. I've been getting "ValueError at /index/todolist/addtodo
Cannot assign "'9'": "Todo.whichlist" must be a "Todolist" instance." with my current setup. Any idea how I can pass the object and not an integer from the html template to my view?

Comment: You can’t. POST parameters are strings. But if you have the id you can fetch the object in your view like you do in the `dolist` view

Comment: Wait it worked!! I changed whichlist= to whichlist_id= in Todo.objects.create() and the app now works as planned. Thank you so much!! I was researching this problem for so long lol. Didn't know it was that simple

Comment: Note that by just relying on the id that’s posted you might end up with a ForeignKey constraint exception: I can modify the HTML in my browser to post any id. If that id doesn’t exist your database will throw an exception. Also I can modify the list of someone else that way. Normally you would check that the corresponding list exists and belongs to the user. Having a `User` foreign key in both models is redundant btw unless multiple users can edit each other’s lists.